# Нужно добавить по одному элементу во вложенные списки из другого списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть три списка одинаковой длины, из них нужно сделать один список со вложенными списками.

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_3 = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]]
```

нужно получить что-то вроде этого

```
list = [[1, 'a', [1, 2]], [2, 'b', [2, 4]], [3, 'c', [3, 6]]]
```

или сделать, чтобы каждый элемент списка поочерёдно записывался в текстовый файл с новой строки, примерно так:

```
1
a
1, 2

2
b
2, 4

3
c
3, 6
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это сделать.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, как вариант:

```py
list(map(list, zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)))
```

Comment: Так всё просто) попробую, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

записать (распечатать) списки в файл построчно:

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        print(list_1[i], list_2[i], sep='\n', file=file)
        print(*list_3[i], sep=', ', end='\n\n', file=file)
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо огромное!